# Get top 5 values from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, max

I have the following array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [count] => 9 
    [user_id] => 2 
) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [count] => 25 
    [user_id] => 1 
) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [count] => 20 
    [user_id] => 3 ) 
[3] => Array ( 
    [count] => 6 
    [user_id] => 56 ) 
[4] => Array ( 
    [count] => 2 
    [user_id] => 37 ) 
[5] => Array ( 
    [count] => 1 
    [user_id] => 0 
))
```

This is just a sample. The actual array will contain many more sub arrays.

I need to be able to obtain the top five values from "count" and store them with their associated "user_id".

The final result needs to look something like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [count] => 25 
    [user_id] => 1 
) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [count] => 20 
    [user_id] => 3
) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [count] => 9 
    [user_id] => 2 
)   
[3] => Array ( 
    [count] => 6 
    [user_id] => 56 
)  
[4] => Array ( 
    [count] => 2 
    [user_id] => 37 
) 
[5] => Array ( 
    [count] => 1 
    [user_id] => 0 
) )
```

If this can be done by simply re ordering the array, that is fine.

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that it's multidimensional doesn't change the problem very much.  You can still use quickselect, and use select sort for the last five elements.

Comment: @Gordon - The array is constructed from a database query and needs to be sorted after the query.

Comment: @user Add a `ORDER BY count DESC` clause to your SQL query. You can also add `LIMIT 5` to restrict it to the first five highest results. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/array_slice).

**Example:**

```
<?php

$array = array(
  array(
    'count' => 9,
    'user_id' => 2
  ),
  array(
    'count' => 25,
    'user_id' => 1
  ),
  array(
    'count' => 20,
    'user_id' => 3
  ),
  array(
    'count' => 6,
    'user_id' => 56
  ),
  array(
    'count' => 2,
    'user_id' => 37
  ),
  array(
    'count' => 1,
    'user_id' => 0
  )
);

function usort_callback($a, $b)
{
  if ( $a['count'] == $b['count'] )
    return 0;
  
  return ( $a['count'] > $b['count'] ) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, 'usort_callback');

$top5 = array_slice($array, 0, 5);

print_r($top5);
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count] => 25
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 20
            [user_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 9
            [user_id] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 6
            [user_id] => 56
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [count] => 2
            [user_id] => 37
        )

)
```

Comment: given that this is a blatant duplicate, you are encouraged to cv the question because it doesnt add any value to the community as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return $b['count'] - $a['count']; });
$top5 = array_slice($array, 0, 5);
```

Comment: given that this is a blatant duplicate, you are encouraged to cv the question because it doesnt add any value to the community as a whole.